Is there a way to change Display Modes for a disabled Monitor and Display Adapter combination?
I was trying to solve an issue with my StarTech 2-port DisplayPort KVM Switch - USB 2.0 - 4K 30Hz, and thought that last bit, 30Hz, or more precisely not being on 30hz, was probably the cause of a black screen on both monitors when both were connected.
It might not have been? I solved it by picking different cables, somehow. Still, this question would be nice to answer:
Is there a way to change the Display Adapter Properties' Display Mode for a monitor/display-adapter combination that has been used before, without having the monitor be on and without installing any third-party programs?
A.k.a an answer that uses Device Manager or PowerShell?
